# Linking Google SignIn and Email/Password login in Mongo Realm

Tags: mongodb, authentication, realm, backend, mongodb-realm

We have used Mongo Realm for our React Native project. I have noticed that while creating an account using the simple create account method and Google sign, even tho we use the same email, two different accounts are created, is there any way to link both these created accounts?

I checked the mongo realm documentation, but it wasn't that big of a help.

[This is how Mongo Team responded to this issue](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/linking-same-user-with-different-authentication-providers/105429/6)

So, is there any other way to link the same user with different authentication providers?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question but isn't this a use case for `user.linkUser(credentials: credentials)`? From the Swift SDK *App Services and the Realm Swift SDK lets you merge multiple credentials into one user identity.* Here's the documentation [Link User Identities](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/users/link-user-identities/)

Comment: So the issue is, ```user.linkUser(credentials: credentials)``` is used when the user does anonymous login initially. 
In my case when the user does authentication through google sign in, and it creates a new user in the DB, even tho a user with similar email id exist. So, it ends up in a situation where there are two different user with same email id. And so when i tried using  ```user.linkUser(credentials: credentials)```  it says that an user with similar ID already exist

Comment: I am not sure that's correct *Auth...lets you merge multiple credentials into one user identity.* and the linkUser can be passed any of a number of credentials. You need to start with a user object and call linkUser on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was

```
const res = await GoogleSignIn();
const ID = res.idToken;
const credential = Realm.Credentials.google({ idToken: ID });
const userID = await realmAppID.logIn(credential);
```

Here, after completing the google sign in we will be getting a new user ID, and user's email.

```
await user.updateOne(
        { email: res.user.email },
        {
          $set: {
            name: res.user.name,
            email: res.user.email,
            profileImage: res.user.photo,
          },
          $addToSet: { userId: Realm.BSON.ObjectID(userID.id) },
        },
        { upsert: true },
      );
```

Here, we would check if an account with a similar email id exists or not, if YES, then we would add the newly obtained userId to the existing user's ID.

We can follow the same method after the user login using email/ password.

**We would change the field userId as an array in the database**

Comment: Does this accomplish what you were asking about in the question? It seems to me that if the user logs in with this code, then logs out and logs in with say, email/pw auth, that will be a totally different user - therefore the accounts are not linked.

Comment: so, what I did was... I connected two different user iD's into one user in the database, by checking if they have similar email IDs. So if the user first logs in using google sign in then uses email/ pw. as both the authentication method have a similar email id so it would connect to one database

Comment: I don't believe this is a good solution to *Linking Google SignIn and Email/Password*. Their user id will not be the same in the client code so that's going to take a lot of additional code to manage two completely different users. Realm heavily relies on the `currentUser` property for authentication, rules and other services; trying to handle a single user across multiple, separate realm accounts sounds like a bad idea. And then what if they change their email address? That would unlink *all* of their data. Glad its working for you but probably not advised as an actual solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not the best solution, but as of now, there wasn't any other solution available. And currently, we don't allow the user to change their email so this method works for now. Until we get an update from the mongo realm team regarding this issue, I don't think we can do anything else.